# Index was outside the bounds of the array. Using PDFStamper and AcroFields to check a CheckBox, but it only works for one out of two PDFs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am not sure why this issue is only happening for one PDFs. I have an ASP webpage set up to take information from Textboxes and such that a user inputs then copies them to a PDF template that I have created. For one of the PDFs I have never have any issues, but the other one gets this error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Application.Page.Function(Object sender, EventArgs e) in {Application Folder}
```

This is not making any sense to me since all the code with these PDFs are the same with different templates. I double checked the CS files, ASPX files, and PDFs if there were any different in the properties or something in the files with no results. I'll post the code here to show that there should be no different that I am missing:

FIRST ASP PAGE:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Checkbox1" />
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Checkbox2" />
```

FIRST CS PAGE:

```
public void submitPage1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
string template = MapPath("Template File Path");
string destination = MapPath("Complete File Destination");

DataTable input = new DataTable();
input.Columns.Add("ActiveCheck", typeof(bool));
input.Columns.Add("InactiveCheck", typeof(bool));

DataRow newRow = input.Row();
newRow["ActiveCheck"] = Checkbox1.Checked;
newRow["InactiveCheck"] = Checkbox2.Checked;

FileStream PDFStream = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Append);
PdfReader templateReader = new PdfReader(template);
PdfStamper newFile = new PdfStamper(templateReader, PDFStream);
AcroFields formFields = newFile.AcroFields;
bool active = (bool)newRow["ActiveCheck"];
bool inactive= (bool)newRow["InactiveCheck"];

if (active) {
String[] firstField = formFields.GetAppearanceStates("ActiveCheckBox");
formFields.SetField("ActiveCheckBox", firstField[1]);
}
if (inactive) {
String[] secondField = formFields.GetAppearanceStates("InactiveCheckBox");
formFields.SetField("InactiveCheckBox", secondField[1]);
}
```

SECOND ASP PAGE:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Complete" />
```

SECOND CS PAGE:

```
public void submitPage1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
string template = MapPath("Template File Path");
string destination = MapPath("Complete File Destination");

DataTable input = new DataTable();
input.Columns.Add("CompleteCheck", typeof(bool));

DataRow newRow = input.Row();
newRow["CompleteCheck"] = Complete.Checked;

FileStream PDFStream = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Append);
PdfReader templateReader = new PdfReader(template);
PdfStamper newFile = new PdfStamper(templateReader, PDFStream);
AcroFields formFields = newFile.AcroFields;
bool finished = (bool)newRow["CompleteCheck"];

if (finished) {
String[] completeField= formFields.GetAppearanceStates("CompleteCheckBox");
formFields.SetField("CompleteCheckBox", completeField[1]);
}
```

***EDIT 1***
I tried changing the code inside the if statement. Now I get no errors, but it will not set the Checkbox to On in the PDF.
Here is what I changed:

```
if (finished) {
formFields.SetField("CompleteCheckBox", "Yes");
}
```

Comment: Have you checked all arrays have values? `firstField`, `secondField` and `completeField` would be my go to.

Comment: @fared Yeah, I have checked. The Checkbox has it's "Checked" values as 1 in the array and 0 for when it's not "Checked". With the First Page, the resulting PDF has the "Checked" value appear properly with no error, but the second page is getting the main error.

Comment: Which line is throwing that error?

Comment: @LajosArpad formFields.SetField("CompleteCheckBox", completeField[1]);
I'm going to try setting the field to "Yes" to see if that might work.

Comment: The issue is that `completeField[1]` is the second element and you have maximum one element there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changes the Checkbox to a Dropdown list with "Yes" and "No" due to the issue I was facing. I am still confused how only one out of the three checkboxes are giving me an error since they are all identical (from what I can tell in the PDFs and the C# code). I will leave this open if anyone can find a reason as to why it is working; however, I have an alternative solution for now. I am aware it is an issue where it is only reading that the last Checkbox does not have a second element, but then why does it work for the other two Checkboxes.